# What do you call it when you regress a dependent variable's variance on some predictors?

Tags: regression, variance, terminology

What do you call it when you regress a dependent variable's **conditional variance** , not its conditional mean, on a set of predictors?

In the "simple" case, I suppose you could figure that each
$Y_i \mid X_i = x_i \sim \text{Normal}(0, \exp[\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i])$, and then maximize the following likelihood:

$$
\prod_i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\exp\left[-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i)/2 - \frac{y_i^2}{2 \exp[\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i]} \right].
$$

This seems like an idea that would have been around for a very long time, but I'm having a surprisingly difficult time searching for resources/references. I keep getting search results for derivations of variance of quantities of the *ordinary* regression models.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do stuff like this, depending on what you have and what you want to accomplish.  But first, how do you propose to measure the conditional variance?  In other words, what data do you have?  Or is this purely a theoretical, mathematical exercise?

Comment: This is motivated by financial returns @whuber. I hesitated to mention that earlier. In that case $y_i$ would be a period's return.

Comment: The Bayesian modeling package `brms` in R has a very elegant implementation where one can specify different models for the mean and the log of the standard deviation and fit the two models simultaneously.

Comment: @FrankHarrell yes I noticed that in their vignette: "[i]n addition, all parameters of the response distribution can be predicted in order to perform distributional regression." Unfortunately he doesn't give this procedure a name, though.

Comment: The GAMLSS package is also a very nice tool for modelling all response distribution parameters (e.g. conditional mean, SD, kurtosis and skewness) as a linear, non-linear or smooth function of one or several predictors. This may be called distributional regression (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2452306221000824).